# Selenium Chrome WebDriver - fail to get cells list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
        WebElement table = a_chromeWebDriver.findElement(By.className("stats-table"));
        List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        system.out.println(allRows.size());

        for (WebElement row : allRows) {

            
            ArrayList<WebElement> cells = (ArrayList<WebElement>) row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    ...
```

I am executing this code on a similar html like this one:

```
<table id="table-type-1" class="stats-table stats-main table-1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="main">
            <th class="aaaa" data-type="rank" title="Rank">
                
            </th>
            A number of headers here...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody title="">
        <tr bla bla bla>
            <td class="bla bla bla" title="bla bla bla>1.</td>
            <td class="bla bla bla"></td>
            <td class="bla bla bla">36</td>
            <td class="bla bla bla">28</td>
            <td class="bla bla bla">3</td>
        </tr>
            <td class="bla bla bla" title="bla bla bla>1.</td>
            <td class="bla bla bla"></td>
            <td class="bla bla bla">45</td>
            <td class="bla bla bla">fnf</td>
            <td class="bla bla bla">kfkfk</td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
```

allRows size gives me a correct number of rows.
For some reason, I get **cells = null**.
I have also tried By.xpath("td") but with no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you loop using this code :

```
 for (WebElement row : allRows) {


        ArrayList<WebElement> cells = (ArrayList<WebElement>) row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        System.out.println("CellCount " + cells.size());
    }
```

**You will see that you get output as :**

```
CellCount 0
CellCount 4
CellCount 4
```

That is because the first row that is picked up by your code is from `<thead>` section where there are no `<td>` elements rest it works fine; so you have to make exception for first `<tr>`

you can do that by changing your allRows element to following:

```
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.xpath("tbody//tr"));
```

Answer (score 2):

First, find all the rows and then iterate over them:

```
  List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#table-type-1 > tbody > tr"));

  for(WebElement row : allRows){
        List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        System.out.println("Cell count: " + cells.size());//cell count for a row
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

A HTML `<table>` consists of 3 sections: `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>`.

Usually you will see only `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.

The correct way is to first identify each of these sections and then work your way through their child elements.

```
// Get the table
WebElement table = a_chromeWebDriver.findElement(By.id("table-type-1"));

// Get the thead in table
WebElement thead = table.findElement(By.tagName("thead"));

// Get the tbody in table
WebElement tbody = table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));

// Get all headers in thead
List<WebElement> allHeaders = thead.findElements(By.tagName("th"));

// Get all rows in tbody
List<WebElement> allRows = tbody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

// Get all cells for each row in allRows
for(WebElement row : allRows) {
    List<WebElement> allCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    int rowNum = allRows.indexOf(row) + 1;
    System.out.println("Row no. " + rowNum + " has " + allCells.size() +" cells.");
}
```